# how to make check-box tap action triggered when is-enabled is false

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox

In my wp8 app i have checkbook in list box and i want to be able to tap check-box when is-enabled is false.i mean i want to tap check box but is-checked shouldn't change

```
<ListBox Name="URLListBox"  Height="Auto" Grid.Row="2"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,10" >   

            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding file}"  x:Name="surename" Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" Content="{Binding text}" Tap="surename_Tap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
         </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: You don't want to tick the checkbox, when that checkbox is tapped right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make by declaring that CheckBox inside Listbox and tick the CheckBox on Listbox tap event. Like this,

```
        <ListBox Name="listBox" Tap="listBox_Tap">
            <CheckBox Content="sample" IsEnabled="False" Name="checkBox" />
        </ListBox>
```

And tick the CheckBox in ListBox tap event.

```
private void listBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

If you have several CheckBox inside that ListBox, get a SelectedIndex in ListBox tap event and change that CheckBox Value. In your case you could refer from the following code, In xaml,

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Tap="RoleslistBox_Tap" Name="RoleslistBox">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" Content="{Binding RoleTypes}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And in RoleslistBox tap event, you could write,

```
private void RoleslistBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = RoleslistBox.SelectedIndex;
        ListBoxItem item = this.RoleslistBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
        CheckBox tagregCheckBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(item);
        tagregCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
    }

private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```